# Doctrine innerOrder[int] column implementation for manual sort order control

Tags: symfony, sorting, doctrine, auto-increment

I have two tables in my app's schema: Event and Game (one-to-many). Games are ordered by datetime field. But sometimes there can be games played in parallel (same datetime), but the user should be able to set their relative order.

I've added `innerOrder` (int) field with simple idea: it should have autogenerated value that can be changed on reorder (exchange with neighbor record). But I can't achieve this behavior with Doctrine: `GeneratedValue` can't be used twice / with separate field (just don't work this way).

On the next attempt I've tried to do it without autogeneration. But I need some initial value on insert, for example: `MAX(innerOrder)` (better - to set it automatically of course).

I can't do it in `prePersist` or similar methods - don't have access to repository class. And don't want to do it with additional query in controller - not only because of additional code I should insert each time (get max value from table, set inner order), but I'm afraid of possible conflicts (when two users are adding Games in parallel).

How should I achieve expected behavior (maybe, I'm totally wrong here)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need in achieving this behavior with Doctrine, you can manage this value from aggregate root. I.e when you attach the `Game` to the `Event` you can update it `innerOrder` value according to maximum of currently attached games + 1. Conflicts could be easily avoided with different kind of locks on `Event` you edit (i.e fetcing it with doctrine write lock or some kind of shared locks or mutex (see symfony/lock))

After it you can specify your relation confiration to fetch it with given order using this documentation

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/tutorials/ordered-associations.html

Answer (score 1):

My two cents: when creating/modifying an event, you can check if there's one already at the same time (default innerOrder is 0, or even count(*) of the events at the same time). You can issue a warning when there's another event, ask for the order, or take to a form where you can manually reassign the order of the events.